# Wrong Function Being Called From MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC view, which is launched by a function in the controller. That view has a button that I want to use to submit data to a different function in that same controller, but it always go back to the function that launched it instead.

The controller is called, the ViewForPrepare view is launched from PrepareList, I hit the button on ViewForPrepare, and it submits to PrepareList again instead of RunList.

In the controller I have:

```
public ActionResult PrepareList(int Key)
{

        return "ViewForPrepare";
}

public ActionResult RunList(int Key)
{

        return "OtherView";
}
```

Then in the View:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Report" id="submit">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () { window.location ='@Url.RouteUrl("RunList", new { Key = @Model.caseNumber })' });
});
</script>
```

So I press the button to go to RunList, but it keeps going to PrepareList. I've checked the routing and it looks OK. What do I need to do to get the button to submit to RunList?

Comment: make sure that your button is just a button and not a submit.

Comment: Ya submit is just what I named it is still just a type=button

Answer (score 1):

You're code right now basically says "When I click the submit button.  Change the window's location to something else."   If that is what you want, try using

```
@Url.Action("RunList", new { Key = Model.caseNumber })
```

instead of

```
@Url.RouteUrl("RunList", new { Key = @Model.caseNumber })
```

and try using a `<button>` element instead of an `<input>` element.

If what you want is to post the data from the form, you should wrap your button in a form tag (make sure to replace "ControllerName" below with your actual controller.)

```
@Html.BeginForm("RunList","ControllerName", new { Key = Model.caseNumber })
{
     <input type="submit" value="Submit Report" id="submit">
}
```

and get rid of the javascript altogether as it isn't necessary in this case.  Also you will have to mark your RunList action as HttpPost for this to work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RunList(int Key)
{
        return "OtherView";
}
```

Comment: This solution is correct All seems to be working now (though I never did get the [HttpPost] thing working, was saying it could not be found in the controller). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use a `RouteLink` instead of the `Input`?

```
@Html.RouteLink("Submit Report", "RunList", new { Key = Model.caseNumber }, new {@class="btn" })
```

not sure if you're using bootstrap or jquery ui but there are css classes to make links look like buttons.

`ActionLink` works the same way.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit Report", "RunList", "ViewForPrepare ", new { Key = Model.caseNumber }, new { @class = "btn" })
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and got the error: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<). " It seems to be putting in a bunch of '%' symbols in the URL. Is there a way to tell it the URL is not dangerous?

I also tried @Url.RouteUrl, which doesn't put anything in the URL, but then goes to the wrong function.

Comment: did you try Action Link? your route doesn't match anything you've posted regarding the controller name and the action name.  Does caseNumber have a lot of symbols?  is there a caseid you can use instead?

Comment: Tried ActionLink and RouteLink. caseNumber is just an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Using VS2015 Pro I created a project using the MVC template.

HomeController.cs added:

```
public ActionResult PrepareList(int Key)
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult RunList(int Key)
{
    return View(); ;
}
```

Index.cshtml added:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Submit Report", "RunList", new { Key = 4 }, new { @class = "btn" })
```

Put a break point in "RunList" and it worked!

Using

```
    <input type="button" value="Submit Report" id="submit">
@section script{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () { window.location ='@Url.RouteUrl("RunList", new { Key = 4 })' });
    });
    </script>
}
```

I got the meessage

```
A route named 'RunList' could not be found in the route collection.
```

Comment: Ya have a routing file that contains 

routes.MapRoute(name: "RunList",
                url: "Home.mvc/RunList",
                defaults: new { controller = "PageReports", action = "RunList" }
            );

Comment: so maybe you need to change your route, and add the parameter Key, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734684/using-url-routeurl-with-route-names-in-an-area

Answer (score -1):

when you need to send data, you must add the attribute HttpPost to this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RunList(int Key)
{
        return "OtherView";
}
```

Comment: Tried that, still going to the wrong function. Also tried <form action="Controller/RunList">

Comment: Hi, when, but, you want to do a post or a get? because, if you have a form, you preffer use post, but I see that you have in javascript a window.location, this call a get, can you explain this? do you have more important cde to share?