# ASP.NET MVC - how to create action link to fit controller/{id}/action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink

I have a route map like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ConversationDetails",
    url: "Conversations/{id}/Details",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Conversations",
        action = "Details"
    }
);
```

and I want to create an `@Html.ActionLink` that will fit my path.
When I'm entering my link, I want to generate the `id` that will follow the controller "`Conversations`" name, and after that I want to add "`Details`" as an action that I want to enter and pass the `id` parameter. Is it possible ?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("xxx", "Details", "Conversations", new { id = someValue }, null)` (assuming your `ConversationDetails` route is before the `Default` route or any other route that would match)

Comment: But this is creating: `/Conversations/Details/1` and I need `/Conversations/1/Details`

Comment: Then your `ConversationDetails` is not the first route in your table! (the order or routes is important)

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. That was not the problem of order, but it was inside route map. Now it works properly and generates my `id` where it should to :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use URL.RouteURL to achieve what you are looking to do.  See this: [Using Url.RouteUrl() with Route Names in an Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734684/using-url-routeurl-with-route-names-in-an-area)

Taken from there and modified:

```
Url.RouteUrl("ConversationDetails", new { id = 5 })
```